# Setting up a large software system in Delphi

Tags: delphi, development-environment, visual-sourcesafe, delphi-xe2, code-organization

We have a software package which is about 16 years old. It's gone through just about every version of Delphi (besides .NET ones). Over the years, things have become very confusing when it comes to cross-referencing and keeping *proper* setup for additional packages (like third-party libraries). I was wondering if there is some *standard practice* when it comes to keeping large projects (and groups of projects) like this organized.

So to explain the current setup...

This is a multi-application system. Meaning, there are 12 executable projects (and a few DLL and service projects) involved. We also keep things in SourceSafe and multiple developers work on the same code on different computers. All of these projects are more-so dumped into a central folder. The "Root" folder contains *THE* major EXE project (along with about 20 folders, all containing units and forms) and it almost seems like an endless hierarchy of folders and files. This one project alone has half a million lines of code involved.

Then all the additional applications aren't necessarily separated properly from this major project. Each of these projects has its own folder based in the main project's root.

The two major concerns of mine are:

- How to properly set up the DCU files so that they aren't mixed in with the projects? DCU's should NOT be placed in the SourceSafe (and any similar file, for that matter) or otherwise, any file compiled from the project. Visual SourceSafe makes files read-only when they're not checked out, and DCU files (and EXE files and more) cannot be written to in this case. So how to properly separate any of such file to a remote location to avoid any mixture with the source code?
- How to properly set up packages and libraries? We have the following:

  - QuickReports 5.05
  - NativeJpg library V302 -
  - Another anonymous reporting library
  - Our own component package, which requires QuickReports, NativeJpg, and the other anonymous library

All 4 of those libraries are stored in completely different places of each computer, and need some centralization. The biggest pain of setting up each new developer's computer is locating these from the *lead developer's computer* and copying them to the same place on each other computer (and making sure the library path is correct, etc.).

We also need to keep completely separate environments for different versions of Delphi on the same computer. This means a copy of the projects on each computer, a copy of packages and libraries on each computer, a copy of the projects and packages and libraries in the SourceSafe, etc. Each computer needs to have an identical setup. We already utilize environment variables to direct our projects where to look for certain project files (and libraries).

Another new concern: XE2 introduces 64bit capabilities. We don't plan on 64bit compiling *yet*, but we certainly will in the future. How do I properly differentiate 32bit from 64bit in all these projects?

What I'm really asking for is a reference to a good tutorial on how to optimize such an environment and keep it organized the best. I don't expect anyone to take the time and answer all this in the question. The projects are over 15 years old, have had the hands of 200+ developers from around the world in it, and has a LOT of cross-referencing between projects. For example, one project may use a unit from another project, and vice-versa. I personally don't like this concept, but I also didn't design it to begin with. I've been given the task to get this system organized and thoroughly documented how to set up Delphi on a new computer for new developers to work on our projects. As I'm looking at our projects (as I'm not necessarily a developer of the system, but am being pulled into development), I'm seeing a lot of confusion in how the code is organized.

I am assuming that possibly Embarcadero has some guidelines and standards on setting up such an environment?

Comment: Step 1 is to get a real revision control system. Sourcesafe is not fit for purpose.

Comment: Great point @DavidHeffernan, I've been trying to get them to upgrade to Subversion. Delphi also has its own repository now - how good is this?

Comment: Delphi has no vcs. Subversion would  be a good choice.

Comment: subversion is behind the times too.  you don't need the ide plugins really.

Comment: @warren subversion is still excellent at what it does. DVCS has its downsides too.

Comment: No VCS can sobsitute a good process. Here the problem is not SourceSafe (which at least has a good GUI most VCSs have not, simplifying use. YOu can change it with the most fashionable VCS actually, and still have problems. Not Subversion, not Git or whatever will help much if he doesn't have clear ideas on how to manage his environment. Throwing more tools (which needs to be mastered...) to a problem is not usually the best way to solve it. First a clear understanding of the issue is needed, then which tools could be help more can be choosen.

Comment: @WarrenP Is "behind the times" code for "not trendy"?

Comment: davea Subversion sounds much better anyway :) "we are using subversion in our company now" - "really? do you know it is a crime in some countries?"

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Totally agree  (and not to put words in your mouth..) The choice of VCS should be based on how your team works rather than what is popular (I'm going to get into trouble for that one too).  I recently reviewed a half dozen or so DVCS solutions, all of which were most excellent (keep an eye on Veracity), but we found no need for what they had to offer.  It doesn't matter what VCS you use, as long as you are using one and it's the right one for you.  (I still have personal projects in CVS and see no reason to move them to anything else)

Comment: Subversion is ideal for a single person, who wants a centralized version control system, and sub-ideal whenever there is more than one person committing.  The big issue I have with Subversion and with CVCS in general is the way it does not permit local commits followed by a separate decision to push the changes to the central server. You can still DO CENTRALIZED VERSION CONTROL with a DVCS. But with a CVCS you have no more choice.  And thus, CVCS < DVCS always.

Comment: By the way, the Web development half of my company does use SVN already and even keep their source in the cloud, and developers can work from home that way. I've been trying to convince the Delphi half of the company to upgrade to SVN to have the same abilities and to keep all our source in the same place.

Comment: Would anyone think that it might be worth creating **NEW** projects in DXE2 and re-adding all the units and forms? I think this might be a good way to refresh our software and make sure it gets all the recommended defaults of creating a new project in XE2.

Comment: @WarrenP: often you want people exactly to "push" changes to the central repository and avoid them working in isolation until it is too late to discover their changes create havoc in the project. There is no "one size fits all" development model. And remember - the best VCS is the one you know better.

Comment: @ldsandon; I used to work that way too, but have replaced the "discover by having someone's commit damage inflicted on me" model to "discover by code review" model. But your mileage may vary.  I found that the collateral damage of seeing all the interim states of commits WAS the only havoc that there was. Completed tested features merge up and are tested once, instead of breaking all developer's work, while work is in progress.  Branching would be one solution in Subversion, if branch merge-tracking in Subversion didn't suck.

Comment: @WarrenP: code review means changes must be available. DVCS are born in environments were people can work a long time in isolation. That's not always true with different kind of applications. But that not means developers should commit at every save. Tools like Delphi have already a "local history" available, a full local repository may be reduntant. IMHO continuos integrations is lesse effective if commits are less often, and the impact of a change is larger than expected. If you can plan everything beforehand it should not happen, but that's not always the case.

Comment: Continuous integration on the trunk of a complex project has been a continuous mess, in my professional experience.

Comment: @Warren Branch merge tracking in svn used to suck, but it works since around 1.6.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Location of DCU files**

Regarding the DCUs that are the output of the compilation process, you should specify a DCU output directory in each project file. The default value for this, in the latest version of Delphi would be fine: `.\$(Platform)\$(Config)`. This results in sub-folders of the project directory like this: `Win32\DEBUG` or `Win64\RELEASE`.

If you set-up your project files using option sets then you will be able to control this setting (and all others) from a small number of option files.

**Location of 3rd party code**

You should always use 3rd party library as code. If the vendor charges more to receive the library as code, pay up. Once you have done so you simply include the source code into your version control system (VCS) and treat it largely the same way as you treat your own code. I say largely because you should avoid modifying it.

Once you have all your code in the VCS then you can put the entire source code onto a new machine with a single checkout operation.

**Organisation of your projects**

I personally have a strong aversion to using compiler search paths. I don't use them and include every unit that is required in a project in the .dpr file.

If you do use search paths then you make it impossible to work on variant projects.So for example, suppose you have a client that has discovered a bug in the version of the software you released 2 years ago. You would like to address that bug by releasing an upgrade to the 2 year old version of the software. It is perfectly plausible that asking them to upgrade to the latest version is not viable. Perhaps they have not paid for the upgrades. Perhaps the full upgrade has breaking changes that they do not want to tackle right now. A perfect example would be all the Delphi developers still using Delphi 7.

Now, having motivated the scenario, how would you create a build environment for the 2 year old project? If you are using search paths then they will refer to today's libraries. You would be forced to change your search path, or copy the old libraries over the top of today's libraries.

That entire headache is trivially side-stepped by not using search paths and by including all your source in the VCS.

What you should be aiming for is to be able to checkout any historic version of your program and have it build immediately. You should be able to do this with full confidence that you are building identical software to what was built at the time that version was released. This also requires you to have build automation but I can't imagine you are lacking that for a project of this size.

Comment: About best practices regarding third party in source control: [Vendor Branches](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html) in the Subversion docs

Comment: +1 for aversion to compiler search paths. I also include all units in the dpr and use the search path only for third party libraries.

Comment: I agree about compiler search paths, but this can be a very difficult change to make. I have thought of making a utility to generate a COMPLETE DPR file, and remove the need for a library path...  Any chance you wrote one already?

Comment: @WarrenP No, we just add the source files to the .dpr manually. We only have a handful of projects and once the project is set-up it changes very seldom.

Comment: @WarrenP: Gexperts' Backup Project utility have the option to locate all included `{$I}` files on library path - so their source can be an starting point.

Comment: The point about search paths is not entirely correct. Using hardcoded, global folders (e.g. "c:\3rdparty\awesomelib\src") in the search path will indeed cause problems with running different versions. Using *relative* paths (e.g. "..\..\3rdparty\awesomelib\src") avoids this problem. You can maintain different branches with different versions of libraries this way.

Answer (score 11):

I'll address folder organisation. This comes from a software suite which has 50+ exe's and dll's and plenty third party libraries, so I guess I know where you are coming from...

We use Perforce as a source control system, so my default workspace's root folder is called Perforce, but I also have a couple of other workspaces set up and they are in Perforce2, Perforce3, etc.

General folder setup (starting from the workspace root folder)

```
General
  Components
    Delphi
      Indy
        Indy9
        Indy10
      MadCollection
        v2.5.8.0
        v2.6.0.0
  Plugins
Releases
  Released
  ... a folder for each release we publish ... (and equal to a branch in Perforce)
Work
  Acceptance
  Sub1
  Sub2
```

My Environment library path in the IDE is empty (not even the BDE standard paths are in there). This ensures that a project's paths declare all path's needed and that projects are not reliant upon a particular machine's IDE setup.

We have an environment var (ie MRJ) set up in our IDE's that points to "General\Components\Delphi" so in a project's options we declare the paths to our components as `$(MRJ)\MadCollection\2.6.0.0`.

General holds IDE plugins and components used by our projects. We keep all versions we use in source control. That way when I have to switch back to an old release to track down a problem, I can simply pull it and build it as its library paths will still point to the version of the components that this specific release needs.

The organisation of folders in a particular work branch (Acceptance or one of its subbranches) follows this pattern:

```
General          
  Includes
  MainComponent1
    Project1
    Project2
    Shared
  MainComponent2  
    Project3
    Project4
    Shared
  Shared
Windows          
  SoftwareSuite  
    Scripts
      Tools
  MainComponent1
    Project1
      Dcus
    Project2
      Dcus
  MainComponent2  
  Tools
    Tool1
      Dcus
    Tool2
      Dcus
```

The General folder holds all platform independent sources/files, the Windows folder holds all Windows specific files. Each component can hold multiple projects and will have a share folder for sources shared between those projects. The shared folder directly under General holds sources shared by all projects. The Windows folder is set up in a similar manner.

Note that **each project has its own dcus folder**. This is configured in the project options. As the path can be entered as `.dcus`, we (at least I) have this set up as the default for any new project. Each project sending its dcus to a unique folder ensures two things:

- it is easy to keep dcu's out of version control by simply setting up a filter in your version control software.
- *more importantly* it ensures that compilation/build of a project **never interferes** with the compilation/build of another project. I can safely change settings and build knowing that I won't be bothered by dcu's lying around from a previous build from another project.

Comment: +1 That's enough info and inspiration for me to write myself a 20 page tutorial for this. I'm already 10 pages into a tutorial on setting up new environments for our software's source. We've pretty much been Windows+SQL based for years, and have just recently started exploring new platforms, like 64bit, mac, phones, etc.

Comment: Which reminds me - I can't wait 'till FireMonkey matures up and comes together. It's still a mess right now - still an art in the working.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend the following practices:

1. Keep your library path simple, and make sure everything in the library path is either a folder that ships with delphi, or a DCU binary (library) folder in your d:\Components\ folder.
2. Use a MODERN type of version control. I recommend Mercurial over others.  Source Safe is crap, stop using it.
3. Back up your environment (export registry keys etc) and restore it to the other developer PCs in a standardized way. You can keep a few .reg and .cmd (batch) files around to automate setup of a new system. you can put these scripts in your component repository in your version control system.

Comment: +1 Agreed on SourceSafe. I have also been thinking of possibly putting together an installation package for developer PC's, including RAD XE2, SQL, registry, source structure, etc.

Comment: @serg is that a comment about svn or is it a preference for dvcs?

Comment: @david after I discovered Mercurial I see no reason to use subversion. Mercurial is better in every aspect that matters for me.

Comment: @Serg It all depends on the process that your team adopts. For my team, we are better suited to centralised than distributed. But clearly other teams will have different processes.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan if you have no access to the central repository from home, you are beginning to hate subversion. DVCS has no problem here.

Comment: @Serg Like I said it all depends on the process

Comment: The lack of locking possibilities is a great disadvantage of Mercurial, although this is mainly a problem for binary files (documents and such) and not for source code.

Comment: @Serg: that's why we remote desktop to our computers at work when working from home. A lot less hassle all ways around, not just wrt version control...

Comment: Teams should have the right to choose a tool that follows their process. If that process involves branching and merging, then Subversion (pre 1.7) just plain sucks, and Subversion 1.7 is (as yet) unproven.  Locking is just a dumb ancient idea, let go of locks, and learn about Lieutenants instead.

Comment: We've actually been contemplating the idea of building one HyperV server and share the source from there via RDP. Each user can have their own session on the same virtual machine, and check-out code as needed from there. No worries about copying source code to local computers, or even installing the same software on all the local computers. Leave it all in the cloud :D (and make sure there's a sufficient back-up routine)

Comment: @jerry I don't understand that. You are proposing not using any vcs at all?

Comment: @warren svn merging was fixed in svn 1.5

Comment: @DavidHeffernan A repository will be available, but everything will be in the same place. Each user uniquely logging into their desktop spawns a new instance of all the software (VCS, IDE, SQL, Etc.)

Comment: @David; Fixed as far as Subversion's model will allow it to be fixed.  I'm not talking about just bugs, but rather what model for merge tracking and branching, one prefers to follow. The subversion model of merge tracking, and branching allow for a natural workflow for me, most of the time.  Local-commit-and-push-to-a-branch provides us with all the benefits of a centralized model, workable branching strategy, and a way to exercise control over who gets to commit to the trunk, and when.    Subversion can be used well, and can do a good job. Just not anywhere I've ever worked.

Answer (score 3):

Outside the scope that was largely discuss before, I would recommend :

- **Unit testing** - with DUnit for example
- **Continuous integration**. Just to be sure that all these projects can compile on another machine and that tests are ok.

So this is heavily related to project organization and VCS strategy.

Comment: Good points even thought they aren't what was asked for.  But adding continuous integration can lead to a desire to make your workstation environment state persisted in version control, so you can more easily set up a server ci build environment.

Answer (score 2):

For a similar setup, a company I worked for found this configuration useful:

- all third party libraries (components etc.) go to a fixed location (C:\Delphi\name-version)
- Delphi projects can be checked out from version control anywhere (drive C: or D: and folder name does not matter), as all projects and scripts use **relative paths**
- all projects are sub folders of one main project folder so checking out this one will bring the Delphi projects and other relevant resources to the workstation, and a version control update is easy to do
- we use a **build script** (written in Apache Ant) which sits in the main folder, and iterates over all folders to build the Delphi apps and **run unit and integration tests** against a development database server, to verify all changes work before checking in to source control
- the build script can also be run automatically on a **build server** (Hudson CI) on every commit to see if something broke

And a note about component libraries: **avoid package installation** where possible, prefer creation of components at run time. If you quickly need to apply a fix to a five year old version of a project, uninstalling / installing a dozen of packages can become frustrating. At least for non-visual components, run-time creation is a huge time saver.

Checking in third party code in source control can be very helpful, for example to share fixes which are not yet available as new official releases. Best practices are covered in the Subversion documentation chapter **[Vendor Branches](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html)**. 
Plus, with Subversion you can use **svn:externals** to place a specific version (tag) right into a project directory structure. This can be used both with third party library and with your own source code, and makes dependency management easier and workstation setup easier.

p.s. the Ant build script defines the search paths for everything, so it is 'the reference' for all developers how to configure the IDE, where to put the third party libs and which compiler flags to use

p.p.s. your project sounds like a lot of fun - I am open for contract work :)

Comment: This breaks down if different main projects need to use different versions of the common sub-projects.

Comment: @David true, there would have to be a separate sub-project folder structure. Subversions svn:externals feature can be used to handle these dependencies, checking out the right version directly into the main project sub folder. I would like to have a Delphi version of [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) too for dependency management.

Comment: +1 and about the package installation, our software requires both QuickReports and also its own component suite (about 10 common components) which requires QR and more. I spent 2 days separating the source from the components which was cross-referencing to the projects. Yeah - The components were referencing a bunch of units in the projects, compiling practically the entire other projects along with it.

Answer (score 2):

My team use virtualization and when we see back it was a real good move. 
We use MacBook Pro laptops and VmWare Fusion, but I'm sure other packages work fine as well like VirtualBox or VirtualPC.

It is always a good feeling to know that when a new developer starts or an old installation got trouble it is just to copy a new VM image from the master image and the setup is **exactly** as the original. The master image is stored on a fast USB2-disk. Now when Thunderbolt and USB3 is coming it would be even faster to copy an image. And there is no real concern about performance on a modern computer as long as there is memory. 8 GB should be enough to run 2 images in parallell. Another advantage of virtualization is that it is so easy to try **What if** scenario. Experiment with different configuarations and versions without any risk to disturb the real working environment.

Btw I also think that SourceSafe is crap... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Somé tips:

- Make one groupproject file for all the apps belonging to the project, each app in its own dir under the groupproj file
- You should be able to specify which file types to include into your version control system. Make sure you set Delphi to write DFM files in text format.
- You could tell Delphi to output DCUs in subdirs named 'dcu' under each app (less visaul clutter).
- Third party stuff often insists on installing in distinct locations, there's not much you can do about it. Make a document describing how to setup a complete working environment and keep it up-to-date
- Develop in virtual machines. A new developer gets a copy of the VM.
- Maintaining for different Delphi versions? Rethink that, try to go to one version. If you absolutely must have two groupprojects and directory structures for each version. [I'm assuming you're not compiling the same app with two Delphi version, that's developer hell]
- Delphi XE2 will output to different 32/64 subdirectories, that should give no problems.